# Flutter: Get latest commit sha

Tags: git, flutter, dart

Is there a way in Flutter to get the latest commit sha? This would be useful to displaying a version number in app.

I have tried loading it from `.git/ORIG_HEAD` like so:

```
final commitId = await rootBundle.loadString('.git/ORIG_HEAD');
```

but receive an error `Could not open '.git/ORIG_HEAD'`

I have also investigated whether it's possible to run a command line query like `git rev-parse HEAD` but this doesn't seem possible in Flutter.

Is there a package or another way of doing this?

For reference - I have done a `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and get the same result

EDIT 1:

Here is my `assets` when trying to import the `.git/` directory:

```
flutter:
    assets:
        - .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

I have also tried with just `.git/` and get the same result.

Comment: Are you trying to run this in a flutter app or just investigating. Because I think the .git folder does not get bundled in the app at all.

Comment: Bit of both. I would like to have it and don't really want to query my vcs to get it as it does exist somewhere locally. I guessed that the folder would not be bundled and that's why it wasn't working and hence the question. This doesn't seem like something that should be difficult, right?

Comment: Hmm, maybe something like [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) solves your needs ?

Comment: Funnily enough, I already am using that package to get my current version number, just thought a commit sha might make it more useful for development with multiple people working on it to understand the latest build. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `.git` folder is not bundled by default. If you want to add, you need to add `.git` folder under the `assets` of your `pubspec.yaml` as you do with an image file. Also, if you're trying this on a Flutter Desktop app; you can use the [run](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.2/dart-io/Process/run.html) method from `dart:io`. It let you run shell commands (depending on your OS you need to trick a little bit in configuration)

Comment: I have added the folder to the `assets` of my `pubspec.yaml` and it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the `assets` part of your `pubspec.yaml`?   I think maybe `/` is missing at the end of the foldername or you can add just the file you want as `.git/ORIG_HEAD`

Comment: I have shared a snippet of my `assets`. I have tried with importing the entire directory with `.git/` and with the specific file `.git/ORIG_HEAD` and neither work. Have you run this locally and saw it working?